# MS Word: How do I format all change tracked text at once?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, editing

For document revisions/reviews my company insists on using tracked changes and manually making changed text blue. You may be wondering why we don’t just use the settings to make that text appear blue. I am wondering that myself. A PDF won’t work either, it should be in MS Word format so reviewers can reply with comments.

So how do I change all the text to blue at once?

(I am using MS Word 2013.)

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: I’ve looked around the track changes controls and other controls on the review tab. I’ve looked at the Home -> Editing -> Select menu. I can’t find anything in MS Word that looks like it’s even a step in the right direction.  I’ve also done google searches but mainly I just find instructions on changing tracked changes settings. (i.e. how to make insertions/deletions appear blue, but not actually change the font color to blue. So on someone else’s computer it would only appear blue if they have their track changes set that way.)

Answer (score 1):

On This page, you will find several macros, that go to each track-changed text/ phrase one by one. These macros are extracting track changed text to excel or word files or just displaying on screen.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/possible-to-export-word-track-changes-information/e0dee9dc-aedb-41d3-92bf-8dc609cc75af?db=5&auth=1

You can take these macros and modify so that you go only to all added track-change text, and then just change the color to blue or whatever you want.

I don't know so much vba, so if you or anyone can do it, please share that modified macro here for me and others also.

Thanks.