# How to select ALL DELETED (or ALL ADDED) text (track change) in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, text-formatting, editing

it is a variation of question 
[MS Word: How do I format all change tracked text at once?](https://superuser.com/questions/896762/ms-word-how-do-i-format-all-change-tracked-text-at-once)

I am finding difficulty in working with the colors given in MS Word (I am at 2016) for track change. The colors are so few, and are so dim or otherwise obscure that track changed deleted/ added text doesn't pop out at screen to catch my attention. Often small sized characters (like . , ; a) are so small that there addition/ deletion goes unnoticed as they are not visible so well and I end up leaving them unattended. underline _ or dash - or separation char – are further problem, because they are used as the style of deletion/ addition in trackchange and if that very character was there and is deleted, or was not there and is added, it is just impossible to figure out because that char then have two meanings.

I have given different colors to addition (red) and to deletion (blue) so it is slightly better, but these are so dull colors that they still fail to catch attention.

I want to select all deleted text in one go and highlight it with (say) yellow,
I want to select all added text in one go and highlight it with (say) green,
I think then it just can't go unnoticed.

I have explored STYLES but couldn't figure out any category for track changed text.

How to select ALL DELETED text and then ALL ADDED text (track change) in one go in MS Word 2016 (w8) to do the above?

Thanks.

added

On This page, you will find several macros, that go to each track-changed text/ phrase one by one. These macros are extracting track changed text to excel or word files or just displaying on screen.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/possible-to-export-word-track-changes-information/e0dee9dc-aedb-41d3-92bf-8dc609cc75af?db=5&auth=1

I don't know so much vba, can someone take any macro from there and modify so that it goes only to all added and/ or all deleted track-change text one by one, and then just change the color or highlight or whatever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I modified a macro from the link you gave. Below works for me in Word 2010, so maybe it works in 2016 too.

```
Sub MarkChanges()
Dim arev As Revision
With ActiveDocument
    For Each arev In .Revisions
        If arev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
            arev.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        ElseIf arev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
            arev.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        End If
    Next arev
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Confirming that it worked perfectly well. wdGreen was too dark (obscuring the text) so I changed that to wdBrightGreen. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

modified endrju's macro to Remove highlights, if one needs that.

```
Sub RemoveHighlightTrackChanges()
Dim arev As Revision
With ActiveDocument
    For Each arev In .Revisions
        If arev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
            arev.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        ElseIf arev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
            arev.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        End If
    Next arev
End With
End Sub
```

Tried it myself. it is working.

Thanks.